# showing TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I can't seem to get this to work I keep getting `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType`

```
#A python program to illustrate Caesar Cipher Technique

import sys, random

class Process:

    def main():
        print("\nA python program to illustrate Caesar Cipher Technique.")
        myMode = getMode()
        if myMode == 'Encrypt':
            myMessage = input("\nEnter the Text You want to be Converted...\n\n")
            myKey = getKey()
            translated = encryptMessage(myKey, myMessage)   
            print ("\nYour Mode        : " + myMode)
            print ("\nYour Text        : " + myMessage)
            print ("\nKey              : " + myKey)
            print ("\nEncrypted Text   : " + translated)
            Testing(myKey, myMessage, translated)
            Exit()
        elif myMode == 'Decrypt':
            myMessage = input("\nEnter the Cipher Text You want to be Decrypted...\n\n")
            Key = keyVal()
            myKey = Key
            translated = decryptMessage(myKey, myMessage)
            print ("\nYour Mode        : " + myMode)
            print ("\nYour Cipher Text : " + myMessage)
            print ("\nKey              : " + myKey)
            print ("\nDecrypted Text   : " + translated)
            Exit()
        else :
            print ("\ntWrong Choice Please Try Again ... \n\n")
            main()


    def getMode():
        mode = input("\nEnter Your Choice for Caesar Cipher Technique\ni.e. Either Encrypt or Decrypt, Type ('Encrypt' or 'Decrypt').\n\n").lower()
        if mode in 'encrypt e decrypt d'.split():
            if mode in 'encrypt e'.split():
                mode = 'Encrypt'
            elif mode in 'decrypt d'.split():
                mode = 'Decrypt'
            else:
                getMode()
        else:
            print("\nOops! Wrong Choice, Please choose Again...\n\n")
            getMode()
        myMode = mode
        return myMode


    def getKey():
        keyMode()


    def keyMode():
        keyMode = input("\nWant to give Key Manually? or Want it to be Auto Generated?\ni.e. Type ('Yes' for Manual or 'Auto' for Auto Generated Key)\n\n")
        if keyMode == 'Yes':
            keyManual()
        elif keyMode =='Auto':
            keyAuto()
        else:
            print("\nOops! Wrong Choice, Please Try Again...\n\n")


    def keyManual():
        key = 0
        minimum = 1
        maximum = 26
        keyMode = 'Manual'
        key = int (input ("\nEnter Your Choice Between %s & %s to be Shift Number as a Key:\n\n" %(minimum, maximum)))
        if (key >= minimum and key <= maximum):
            return key
        else:
            print("\nOops! Wrong Choice, Please choose between %s & %s, Try Again...\n\n" %(minimum, maximum))
            keyManual()
        myKey = int(key)


    def keyAuto():
        minimum = 1
        maximum = 26
        total = maximum + 1
        keyMode = 'Auto'
        myKey = random.randint(minimum, total)
        return myKey


    def keyVal():
        key = 0
        minimum = 1
        maximum = 26
        keyMode = 'Validation'
        key = int (input ("\nEnter the Key provided to You...\n\n"))
        if (key >= minimum and key <= maximum):
            return key
        else:
            print("\nOops! Wrong Key, Please Try Again...\n\n")
            keyVal()
        myKey = int(key)


    def Testing(myKey, myMessage, translated):
        Test = input("\nDo you want to Check what your Original Text was by Decrypting Message?\n\ni.e.(Type 'Yes'/'No')\n\n")
        if Test == 'Yes':
            myMode = 'Decrypt'
            Key = myKey
            myKey = Key
            Encrypted = translated
            myMessage = Encrypted
            translated = decryptMessage(myKey, myMessage)
            print ("\nYour Mode        : " + myMode)
            print ("\nYour Cipher Text : " + myMessage)
            print ("\nKey              : " + myKey)
            print ("\nDecrypted Text   : " + translated)
        elif Test == 'No':
            print ("\nThank You...!\n")
        else:
            print ("\nWrong Choice Please Try Again ... \n\n")
            Testing(myKey, myMessage, translated)


    def encryptMessage(key, message):
        return translateMessage(key, message, 'Encrypt')


    def decryptMessage(key, message):
        return translateMessage(key, message, 'Decrypt')


    def translateMessage(key, message, mode):
        translated = ''
        if mode == 'Decrypt':
            key = -key
        for symbol in message:
            if symbol.isalpha():
                num = ord(symbol)
                num += key
                if symbol.isupper():
                    if num > ord('Z'):
                        num -= 26
                    elif num < ord('A'):
                        num += 26
                elif symbol.islower():
                    if num > ord('z'):
                        num -= 26
                    elif num < ord('a'):
                        num += 26
                translated += chr(num)
            else:
                translated += symbol
        return translated


    def Exit():
        Exit = input ("\nDo You want to Run the Program again? (Type 'Yes'/'No')\n\n")
        if Exit == 'Yes':
            main()
        else:
            print ("\n          --/--\--/End\--/--\-- \n\n")

Process.main()

input()
```

Comment: Please cut this down to a [mcve].

Comment: You're adding an integer to None: the error message is crystal clear. So you find the line number it's happening on, you print the two objects being added, thereby learning which is None, then you ask yourself why None is None...

Comment: What line is the error on? A complete traceback would help to identify the problem